# Better code prediction in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pydev, code-completion

I'm trying various IDE for development on Python. Basic requirement better code-prediction and git association. I really liked PyCharm, but code-prediction is somewhat better in PyDev.

Here is a comparison of code prediction side-by-side (Left - PyDev, Right - PyCharm)

[image: PyDev]
[image]

Here is What I've tried so far -

1) Restart, Re-install

2) Enabled `Collect run-time types information for code insight`

(UPDATE)

Code is being predicted, when I'm using Python Console in PyCharm, but not in editor.
[image: Python Console in PyCharm]

Comment: The console case is much simpler for an IDE because in the console you have actual live objects which can be inspected for type and attributes. Static source code needs much more effort analyse and trying to infer the types and attributes of objects.

Answer (score 1):

You will be surprised but if you are using windows try VS community edition with Python plugin. intellisense just works.